# "Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue" while trying to change char* pointer location

Tags: c, cstring

I'm writing a little function in C that eliminates leading whitespace, but it's giving me the "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

```
char str1[20];
strcpy (str1, otherStr);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
{
    if (!isspace(str1[i]))
        str1 = &(str1[i]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? (And yes, otherStr is defined)

Comment: You can't change where an array is, it's statically allocated by the compiler at time of compilation. It's true that arrays *decays* to pointers, but they are not pointer. If you want to use it as a true pointer, then you need to use an actual pointer.

Comment: There's no `char * ` pointer in your code. Array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `char *` pointer in your code, which one could possibly change. Array is not a pointer. You can't "change" its location.

In C language arrays objects themselves are *non-modifiable* lvalues, which is where the wording of the error stems from.

Comment: `&(str1[i])` is a `char *`, I'm not sure OP understands it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str1 = malloc(20);
// or
// char s[20];
// char * str1 = s; // note the lack &s
// or
// char *str1 = alloca(20);
strcpy (str1, otherStr);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
{
    if (!isspace(str1[i]))
        str1 = &(str1[i]);
}
```

Your code didn't work because when `char str1[20]` then str1 is not a variable -- for most purposes it is a pointer literal, similar to `(void *)0x0342` would be.  You can't do `0x0342 = 7;` so you can't assign to an array name either.